# How to install node.js

Tags: node.js, n

I did the following:

```
user@machine:~$ sudo n stable
   installed : v12.13.0 (with npm 6.12.0)
user@machine:~$ node --version
v8.10.0
user@machine:~$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
user@machine:~$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v12.13.0
```

I was expecting v12.13.0 to be installed, but `node --version` reveals v8.10.0.

What did I do wrong?  How do I get v12.13.0 installed?  FYI I am on Jetson Nano and I'm really just trying to get LTS Nodejs installed and don't know how.

BTW, if I do `sudo apt-get install nodejs` I only get v8.10.0.

**MORE INFO:**

```
user@machine:~$ node --version
v8.10.0
user@machine:~$ sudo node --version
v12.13.0
```

Seems `sudo` is affecting this somehow?

(I'm not very familiar with linux, but I'm learning ... sorry if I'm missing "obvious" stuff.)

Comment: from this `sudo apt-get install nodejs` I get the feeling you are using a linux(debian distro) right

Comment: You may have more than one `node` installed, or some kind of alias for `node`? Check that in your path `/usr/local/bin` comes earlier than others.

Comment: @kellymandem I'm on Jetson Nano.  So I guess so.  It's linux, ARM.  `Linux version 4.9.140-tegra (buildbrain@mobile-u64-3561) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180425 [linaro-7.3-2018.05 revision d29120a424ecfbc167ef90065c0eeb7f91977701] (Linaro GCC 7.3-2018.05) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 12 21:16:23 PDT 2019`

Comment: @tadman, clearly something like that may be up.  How do I resolve it?

Comment: ATTN: downvoter, please let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: You may want to hunt around with like `find / -name node` to see where others are lurking.

Comment: `sudo` seems to somehow change the version.  I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: `sudo` may have different PATH and different shell command cache. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the problem by forgoing the use of ***n***.

Here's how to install directly from the dist at nodejs.org.

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.10.0/node-v12.13.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xf node-v12.13.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange...

Could you try something?

```
mv /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node.back
which node
mv /usr/local/bin/node.back /usr/local/bin/node
```

I just want to see what produce `which` if you remove the old node version binary.

Also provide more info about file `/usr/local/bin/node`, is it a symbolic link? If true, to what?

Comment: That shows `/usr/bin/node`,  which is v8.10.0.  I think you may be onto something.  how do I fix?

Comment: Well I don't know nothing about `n stable` but it seems to be a version manager... maybe you should see with their doc. Cause the you clearly have a little problem. Or just do what @Rustan propose in his solution, not beautifull but working :) Another great solution could be to remove NodeJS AND your version manager and goes to Node Version Manager (NVM)... great tools

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/node` is the v12.13.0 node, it's an actual file, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment but try replacing `/usr/bin/node` with a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin/node`. Had similar issue some time ago that ate my brain. Solved it like this.

P.S don't forget to backup

Answer (score 0):

1) Try opening a new shell and checking what version of node you see there.

`n` installs the node binary by default to `/usr/local/bin/node`. You may already have had a node binary installed to `/usr/bin/node`, and your shell cache of known commands (paths) may be running the old one.

Example of problem with bash: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/588

2) If your OS has the command, you can run `which -a node` to see if you have multiple versions and where they are installed. (Uninstalling the ones you don't want reduces potential for confusion.)

3) Check the location of the intended version is in your PATH. If you are using `n`, try running `n doctor`. There are some extra checks that the version of node found is the one that is the one that `n` installed.